# Gwt architecture : why use MVP, Editors, RequestFactory, Gin etc?

Tags: gwt, architecture

I've been working for a year now on a GWT application, and we never felt the need to use any of these frameworks or tools.

So i feel like we're probably missing out.

We do it "code behind" style.

Here's a simple example on how we build our code :

MyPanel.ui.xml :

```
<label ui:field="label"/>
<g:TextBox ui:field="box"/>
<g:Button ui:field="button"/>
```

MyPanel.java :

```
@UiField
LabelElement label;
@UiField
TextBox box;
@UiField
Button button;

MyBean myBean;

Messages messages = GWT.create(Messages.class);
MyServiceAsync myServiceAsync = GWT.create(MyService.class);

...


protected void i18n() {
  label.setInnerText(messages.label());
  button.setText(messages.button());
}

...

@UiHandler("box")
void box_onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
  myBean.setText(event.getValue());
}

@UiHandler("button")
void button_onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  myServiceAsync.sendData(myBean, new AsyncCallback<MyResponse>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(ReponseDispoBean result) {
       Window.alert(result.message());
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
       Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
     }
  });
}
```

To communicate between panels (portions of pages, each in its own class), we use the widget's or the application's eventbus to send custom events.

To navigate we use the places/tokenizers/activities and the historymapper

And for unit and functionnal tests, we use [gwt-test-utils](https://github.com/gwt-test-utils/gwt-test-utils)

And that's it. So i'm wondering : what pain those tools help with ? What compelling reason is there to use them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

**Editors** and **GIN** deal with reducing boilerplate.
For instance, compare the same *screen* [without](https://gist.github.com/780560/40d2fdefa97f8b7a73a1bbc0d78b122508c0a2b1) and [with](https://gist.github.com/780560/bb0fab5593f873f8bfddefe1b3047bd72ef76cfd) Editors.
And when I say that GIN deals with reducing boilerplate, it's only if you already use **dependency-injection** (DI). If you don't use DI, then well, [you probably should](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/).

Similarly to DI, **MVP** helps with making testable code, particularly about testing the *presentation logic* (not necessarily the *business logic*, and not the UI). For instance, it doesn't really matter *how* you display something, what matters is that you display the right thing at the right time. One example would be errors: it doesn't really matter if they're in red at the top of the screen, or next the the form field, or in a tooltip on the form field which then turns red; what matters is that you *send to the view* the correct set of errors, at the right time. The *how* can be replaced or modified (and should ideally also be tested), but the *what* is the same.
MVP can also be great when building multi-factor apps: if the *screens* can be similar enough between mobile, tablet and desktop, then you can use the same presenter with 3 different views (and that's where DI shines!).

As for **RequestFactory** (RF), well, it's a different client-server protocol than GWT-RPC, with its own set of features and limitations. If you don't have an issue with GWT-RPC, you shouldn't switch (though I'd recommend you look at what RF is). To me, the major feature of RF is that it's a protocol (based on JSON) more than an API: the classes on the client and the server don't have to be exactly the same, provided they are *compatible enough* that the client and server understand each others (add a property, change an `int` to a `double`, etc.); this is a huge difference compared to GWT-RPC, where you'll have an error even for a very minor and subtle change in your classes.

But in the end, “[if it ain't broke, don't fix it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_it_ain%27t_broke,_don%27t_fix_it)”.

Answer (score 2):

MVP just separates logic from view code and helps to run test in jvm instead of using slow GWTTestcase.

Editors helps to bind object properties to input fields. This makes code to copy from and to inputs fields into your objects obsolete.

Gin helps to wire your objects. Again, this makes testing a lot easier. You can wire your objects by yourself of cause but why should you do that if gin does that automatically for you?

RequestFactory is a replacement for the RPC approch and is more data centric. It helps you to fetch data in batch operation an it makes the use of DTO obsolete. 
You can of cause stick with the RPC approach. But there are some drawbacks. You have to create a Serverlet for every Service or you can use the command pattern. That leads to the problem, that you have to create an Action, Response and a handling Service for very request. This is a lot of code to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing I might suggest taking a look at is RequestFactory vs gwt rpc. It does not require objects to be serializable and has quite a few performance enhancements such as sending only diff's over the wire.

We also use the ClientFactory pattern which resembles gin. We use this to inject a client class depending on the device type that is being used (tablet, mobile, desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is ok. In fact, I have started many of my prototype projects like this (instead of gwt-test-utils, for such projects I simply use GWTTestCase). And you know, sometimes this is all that is needed, and everything else would only add complexity! So it's not only ok for prototypes, but may indeed work very well for some real projects.

But more often than not, it turns out, that I want to re-use some components, and make them more configurable. And this is the time I refactor to MVP. And Gin if I haven't already (actually, nowadays I usually start all projects with Gin).

So you can add these things, when *you* discover a need for them, or a certain advantage (not because they are theoretically great, or "hip").

By the way, I don't use the event bus approach (except for small, well-defined sets of events), because the complexity of event systems typically explodes.